# android studio it's good to use bind service on background service?

Tags: android, android-service

I am creating an chat app which is connected to `web socket`, using a background service. But I should connect it to the activity to show the new messages. Maybe in the main conversations list, or inside the conversation itself.

So, first, I want to check if my service is running, then getting it bound to the opened activity.
And I want the service to tell the activities that there is a new message.

So, is it good to do it using `'bindService'`? Because I feel that there's something not right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can send messages from the Service to Activities with the BroadcastReceiver class. I would get your information from the following link:

https://developer.android.com/guide/components/broadcasts